# Do Domain transfer to another registrar all details of related to domain record

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, domain-transfer

We need to transfer domain from another registrar to network solution, when domain transfer is initiated and completed will domain transfer to done with all the details like www,MX, A SPF record or we have to update all these records after domain transfer is complete.

Comment: It all depends upon where your DNS records exist. Most of the time, they exist with the registrar and not the web host. It depends upon a persons experience while setting up a domain in the first place, whether they had a personal preference, or even simply followed a web hosts instructions to use the web hosts DNS without understanding what it all means. You will have to figure that part out first.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that if the nameservers point away from the registrar i.e. the DNS is hosted elsewhere, then a change of registrar does not affect DNS at all.

Answer (score 1):

All the registrar holds on you is your account information and name server entries, your DNS records are hosted by your DNS host which in many instances is the same as your web host. Just transfer the domain name and give them your name server addresses and within 48 hours it should be fine.